# Why won't my test file import my datastructure? Haskell

Tags: haskell, data-structures, import, hunit

I am currently writing unit tests for my (very simple) blackjack game and my testfile (Tests.hs) does not seem to import my datastructures that I have declared in the file I am doing unit tests for (HelpFunctions.hs). I can acces the functions/methods in this file but not the datastructures. 
Can someone please help me find the problem?

This is the top of my testfile:

```
module Tests(performTests) where
import Test.HUnit
import HelpFunctions

cardList = [(Hearts, Ace)]
(...)
```

and this is the top of the file that i am going to write tests for

```
module HelpFunctions(Suit, Value, blackjack, cardDeck, shuffleOne, 
                     shuffleCards, getValue, addHand, dealCard, bust, 
                     getHighest
                    ) where

import System.Random
import Control.Monad(when)

{- Suit is one of the four suits or color of a playing card 
   ie Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds or Spades
   INVARIANT: Must be one of the specified.
 -}
data Suit = Hearts | Clubs | Diamonds | Spades deriving (Show)

{- Value is the numeric value of a playing card according to the rules of blackjack. 
   INVARIANT: Must be one of the specified.
 -}
data Value = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | 
             Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen | King | Ace 
             deriving (Eq, Show)
(...)
```

And when compiling the testfile I get the error

```
    Tests.hs:6:14: error: Data constructor not in scope: Hearts
  |
6 | cardList = [(Hearts, Ace)]   |              ^^^^^^

Tests.hs:6:22: error: Data constructor not in scope: Ace
  |
6 | cardList = [(Hearts, Ace)]   |                      ^^^
```

I have another file that import HelpFunctions and the datastructures from it and that work without problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
module HelpFunctions(Suit, Value, ...
```

This line says `HelpFunctions` exports the types `Suit` and `Value`, but not their data constructors (i.e. the types are abstract).

You want

```
module HelpFunctions(Suit(..), Value(..), ...
```

You could list all constructors explicitly, but the `..` shorthand notation means "all data constructors of this type".

---

Reference: [The Haskell 2010 Language Report, **5.2 Export Lists**](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1000005.2):

> 2. An algebraic datatype *T* declared by a `data` or `newtype` declaration may be named in one of three ways:
>
>    - The form *T* names the type *but not the constructors or field names*. The ability to export a type without its constructors allows the construction of abstract datatypes (see Section [5.8](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1150005.8)).
>    - The form *T(c<sub>1</sub>,…,c<sub>n</sub>)*, names the type and some or all of its constructors and field names.
>    - The abbreviated form *T*`(..)` names the type and all its constructors and field names that are currently in scope (whether qualified or not).

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved it.
Im curious though, how come it worked when using my other file that imports HelpFunctions.hs?

Comment: @Meltdown: well if `HelpFunctions` only export *functions*, then there is no second degree export. With `Suit(..)` you do not only export the *type*, but also the constructors, but a function (like `foo`) has no constructors.